# Tensorflow 2.0 Warnings - dense_features is casting an input tensor from dtype float64 to the layer's dtype of float32

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am reading over the Tensorflow 2.0 google website [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns#numeric_columns), where they discuss the Feature Columns API. In the second in which they discuss numeric columns, the sample code generates the warning below. The warning seems to be about casting some data, but the message does not exactly explain how to fix the problem--that is, where should the user explicitly cast the data so that this warning is avoided.:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer dense_features is casting an input tensor from dtype 
float64 to the layer's dtype of float32, which is new behavior in TensorFlow 
2.  The layer has dtype float32 because it's dtype defaults to floatx.

If you intended to run this layer in float32, you can safely ignore this 
warning. If in doubt, this warning is likely only an issue if you are porting 
a TensorFlow 1.X model to TensorFlow 2.

To change all layers to have dtype float64 by default, call 
`tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')`. To change just this layer, pass 
dtype='float64' to the layer constructor. If you are the author of this layer, 
you can disable autocasting by passing autocast=False to the base Layer 
constructor.
```

I am trying to figure out how to fix this warning, because it is showing up on some of my own code too. The code to generate this warning is:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv'
dataframe = pd.read_csv(URL)
train, test = train_test_split(dataframe, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)
print(len(train), 'train examples')
print(len(val), 'validation examples')
print(len(test), 'test examples')

def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe.pop('target')
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds

batch_size = 5 # A small batch sized is used for demonstration purposes
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

# We will use this batch to demonstrate several types of feature columns
example_batch = next(iter(train_ds))[0]

# A utility method to create a feature column
# and to transform a batch of data
def demo(feature_column):
  feature_layer = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_column)
  print(feature_layer(example_batch).numpy())

age = feature_column.numeric_column("age")
demo(age) # <-- SHOULD TRIGGER OR DISPLAY THE WARNING
```

Any suggestions about how to fix this?

Comment: Seems the warning says what needs to be done: To change all layers to have dtype float64 by default, call 
`tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')`. To change just this layer, pass 
dtype='float64' to the layer constructor. ?

Comment: @thushv89 I did not try that, but it seems like it kind of ignores the underlying problem. So somehow some values are getting cast as the wrong float type, and this fix with `tf.keras.backend.set_floatx()` is like a catch-all to deal with that. But how did the wrong type get assigned in the first place. How can I manually change that type--like where would I change that type if I did not use this catch-all function.

Comment: Doesn't changing to `layers.DenseFeatures(feature_column, dtype='float64')` work?

Comment: Nope. That did not work. I still get the same error. I actually tried "float64" and "int64" and I still get the same error in either case--`TypeError: Cannot convert 1.0 to EagerTensor of dtype int64`. So seems like the error is happening somewhere else or in the parsing of the data into the Feature Column.

Comment: Actually `layers.DenseFeatures(feature_column, dtype='float64')` all I needed to make the warning go away. Didn't that work for you?

Comment: Oh yes, it does work now. That fixed it. I think I ran my own test file from the wrong location on my first try. But when I tried it again, this did fix the problem.

Comment: @thushv89 thanks for your help. Glad this problem is resolved at least :).

Comment: The problem is that the input to the layer has tf.float64 dtype, while the layer has tf.float32 parameters, since it isthe default in tf. So you just have to cast one of the two to the other.

Comment: @GiuseppeMarra That makes sense. How do I cast inside of a feature column? That is what was confusing me. Like do I wrap the feature column with the cast, like `age = tf.cast(feature_column.numeric_column("age"), tf.float32)` or something. Do you know the proper syntax for this type of casting? Thanks.

Comment: The input to the layer is `example_batch`. This should be casted. The dataset has been created using doubles, so it produces tf.float64 tensors.

Comment: @GiuseppeMarra Oh I get what you mean. So you are talking about having a `parse()` function and then using a `.map()` applied to the batch. Yeah, I see what you mean. I have used that for like TFRecords files, but the same idea could apply to probably any Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** to silence this warning, manually cast your input to `float32`

```
X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32) 
y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)
```

or with `numpy`:

```
X = np.array(X, dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array(y, dtype=np.float32)
```

**Explanation**

By default, Tensorflow uses `floatx`, which defaults to `float32`, because it's more than enough for deep learning. You can verify this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.floatx()
```

```
Out[3]: 'float32'
```

The input you provided, is of dtype `float64`, so there is a mismatch between Tensorflow's default dtype for weights, and the input. Tensorflow doesn't like that, because casting (changing the dtype) is costly. Tensorflow will generally throw an error when manipulating tensors of different dtypes (e.g., comparing `float32` logits and `float64` labels).

The *new behavior* it's talking about:

> Layer my_model_1 is casting an input tensor from dtype float64 to the layer's dtype of float32, which is new behavior in TensorFlow 2

Is that it will automatically cast the input dtype to `float32`. Tensorflow 1.X probably threw an exception in this situation, although I can't say I've ever used it.