# WARNING:tensorflow:Layer my_model is casting an input tensor from dtype float64 to the layer's dtype of float32, which is new behavior in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Before my Tensorflow neural network starts training, the following warning prints out:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Layer my_model is casting an input tensor from
> dtype float64 to the layer's dtype of float32, which is new behavior
> in TensorFlow 2.  The layer has dtype float32 because it's dtype
> defaults to floatx. If you intended to run this layer in float32, you
> can safely ignore this warning.

> If in doubt, this warning is likely
> only an issue if you are porting a TensorFlow 1.X model to TensorFlow
> 2. To change all layers to have dtype float64 by default, call `tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')`.

> To change just this layer,
> pass dtype='float64' to the layer constructor. If you are the author
> of this layer, you can disable autocasting by passing autocast=False
> to the base Layer constructor.

Now, based on the error message, **I am able to silence this error message** by setting the backend to `'float64'`. But, I would like to get to the bottom of this and set the right `dtypes` manually.

Full code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris, target = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

X = iris[:, :3]
y = iris[:, 3]

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y)).shuffle(25).batch(8)

class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.d0 = Dense(16, activation='relu')
    self.d1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(1, activation='linear')

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.d0(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    x = self.d2(x)
    return x

model = MyModel()

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-4)

loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='loss')
error = tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()

@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(inputs)
        run_loss = loss_object(targets, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(run_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    loss(run_loss)
    error(predictions, targets)

for epoch in range(10):
  for data, labels in ds:
    train_step(data, labels)

  template = 'Epoch {:>2}, Loss: {:>7.4f}, MSE: {:>6.2f}'
  print(template.format(epoch+1,
                        loss.result(),
                        error.result()*100))
  # Reset the metrics for the next epoch
  loss.reset_states()
  error.reset_states()
```

Comment: Recommendations of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188056/tensorflow-2-0-warnings-dense-features-is-casting-an-input-tensor-from-dtype-f#comment104598715_59188056) question might be able to help you.

Comment: I see that it's related the comments aren't very clear and no answer has been posted. Feel free to provide an answer based on the code I provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr** to avoid this, cast your input to `float32`

```
X = tf.cast(iris[:, :3], tf.float32) 
y = tf.cast(iris[:, 3], tf.float32)
```

or with `numpy`:

```
X = np.array(iris[:, :3], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array(iris[:, 3], dtype=np.float32)
```

**Explanation**

By default, Tensorflow uses `floatx`, which defaults to `float32`, which is standard for deep learning. You can verify this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.floatx()
```

```
Out[3]: 'float32'
```

The input you provided (the Iris dataset), is of dtype `float64`, so there is a mismatch between Tensorflow's default dtype for weights, and the input. Tensorflow doesn't like that, because casting (changing the dtype) is costly. Tensorflow will generally throw an error when manipulating tensors of different dtypes (e.g., comparing `float32` logits and `float64` labels).

The "new behavior" it's talking about:

> Layer my_model_1 is casting an input tensor from dtype float64 to the layer's dtype of float32, which is new behavior in TensorFlow 2

Is that it will automatically cast the input dtype to `float32`. Tensorflow 1.X probably threw an exception in this situation, although I can't say I've ever used it.