# broken tensorflow keras function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have this function that used to work and broke when I updated or upgrade to tensorflow 2.

```
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe.pop('SalePrice')
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds

batch_size = 32
train_ds = df_to_dataset(df_train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(df_validation, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
df_test['SalePrice'] = 0
test_ds = df_to_dataset(df_test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)


feature_columns = []

for col in numericColumns:
  col = feature_column.numeric_column(col)
  feature_columns.append(col)

for col in categoricalColumns:
  col = feature_column.indicator_column(feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(col,df_train[col].unique()))
  feature_columns.append(col)

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)



from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    feature_layer,
    layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

  model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'])
  return model

model = build_model()
```

When I try to fit the model, I am getting sll types of warnings:

```
history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds,  epochs=30)
```

The following warnings are posted and I am not sure if the model is fitted properly:

```
Epoch 1/30
WARNING:tensorflow:Layers in a Sequential model should only have a single input tensor, but we receive a <class 'dict'> input: {'Id': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_40:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'MSSubClass': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_50:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'MSZoning': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_51:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'LotFrontage': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_47:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'LotArea': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_45:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'Street': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_67:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'LotShape': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_48:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'LandContour': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_43:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'Utilities': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_70:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'LotConfig': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_46:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'LandSlope': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_44:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'Neighborhood': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_56:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'Condition1': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_16:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'Condition2': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_17:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'BldgType': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_4:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'HouseStyle': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_39:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'OverallQual': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_59:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'OverallCond': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_58:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'YearBuilt': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_72:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'YearRemodAdd': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_73:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'RoofStyle': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_63:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'RoofMatl': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_62:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'Exterior1st': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_22:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'Exterior2nd': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_23:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'MasVnrType': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_53:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'MasVnrArea': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_52:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'ExterQual': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_21:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'ExterCond': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_20:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'Foundation': <tf.Tensor 
'ExpandDims_25:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'BsmtQual': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_13:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'BsmtCond': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_5:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'BsmtExposure': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_6:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'BsmtFinType1': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_9:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'BsmtFinSF1': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_7:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'BsmtFinType2': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_10:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'BsmtFinSF2': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_8:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'BsmtUnfSF': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_14:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'TotalBsmtSF': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_69:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'Heating': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_37:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'HeatingQC': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_38:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'CentralAir': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_15:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'Electrical': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_18:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, '1stFlrSF': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, '2ndFlrSF': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'LowQualFinSF': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_49:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'GrLivArea': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_35:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'BsmtFullBath': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_11:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'BsmtHalfBath': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_12:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'FullBath': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_26:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'HalfBath': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_36:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'BedroomAbvGr': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_3:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'KitchenAbvGr': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_41:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'KitchenQual': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_42:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'TotRmsAbvGrd': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_68:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'Functional': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_27:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'Fireplaces': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_24:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'GarageType': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_33:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'GarageYrBlt': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_34:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'GarageFinish': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_31:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'GarageCars': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_29:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'GarageArea': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_28:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'GarageQual': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_32:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'GarageCond': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_30:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'PavedDrive': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_60:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'WoodDeckSF': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_71:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'OpenPorchSF': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_57:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'EnclosedPorch': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_19:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, '3SsnPorch': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_2:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'ScreenPorch': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_66:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'PoolArea': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_61:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'MiscVal': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_54:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'MoSold': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_55:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'YrSold': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_74:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'SaleType': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_65:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, 'SaleCondition': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_64:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>}
Consider rewriting this model with the Functional API.
```

I tried to review the tensorflow doc on Google[https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential] but can's seem to understand how to repair or rewrite the function to work properly.

Any help or assistance/recommendations with getting it right would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `feature_layer` in your model?

Comment: please see updated code block (first one on top...)

Comment: did you try adding this line at the top of your code `tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')`.

Comment: Yes, I added the float32 instead because the data are already set to float64 and it is the complaint.  That issue is resolved, but what about the first warning about "Consider rewriting this model with the Functional API"?  How do I correct that?

Comment: I think the warning is fine, if you look at the example by TensorFlow as well, it also has the warning: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv

Comment: You [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59400128/10908375) change the backend to `float64`, you'll run out of memory.

Comment: Try casting all input to the same dtype, e.g., `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key, vocabulary_list, dtype=tf.float32)`

Comment: The complaint is that you are passing a dictionary of inputs during training, but a Sequential model only expects one input (a dictionary represents multiple inputs). Can you please update your question with how `train_ds` is defined?

Comment: train_ds code has been added to the top block...

Comment: I ran your code with a [toy dataset](https://github.com/nicolas-gervais/functions-to-save-time/blob/master/pandas-df-for-stack-overflow-office) and it worked for me. I have TF 2.1

Comment: so, it is alright as is and does not need to be rewritten with the functional API, as indicated?

Comment: It's hard to advise what to do because I [ran your code](https://github.com/nicolas-gervais/functions-to-save-time/blob/master/stack_temporary) on a toy dataset and it works.

Comment: Looks like it is okay. The same warning exists in their documentation as well https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns#create_compile_and_train_the_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tensorflow documentation has reported the warnings as a normal process and output in some situations: [TensorFlow Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns#create_compile_and_train_the_model)