# Re-Scale Training Set

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm training a DL model in Tensorflow 2.1. I prepared a training set of several greyscale (1-channel) images.
I have seen that it is recommended to normalize the training set by dividing it by 255.0, so that the values are inside the range [0-1]. So I have some questions regarding it:

- Why is this normalization recomended?
- My target masks contain values from 0-1 and are float 64. Is it valid to use this data type?
- Finally, Should I normalize the images that I use for future predictions as well, or can I just leave them as 8-bit images (0-255).

Comment: I answered your question, but it is highly likely that it will be soon closed due to the number of questions. As a recommendation, the next times you ask questions you should focus them better (leave only one instead of 3)

Comment: I will not vote to close it since I consider that you may learn from these comments here.

Comment: Alright! Lesson learnt. I didnt create different posts since I the questions were interrelated but I'll do so in the future. Thank you.

Comment: It really depends on the reviewer. It is logical that they are interrelated in this case, but the tendency of the reviewer is to close it considering that is looks over many bullet points with questions. Plus, someone who could really want to uphold their argument could ask "What has the normalization process to do with "future predictions test". You are welcome btw, it's important for all of us here to learn.

Comment: This question is also not directly related to, and answerable by, programming. At least two of these are purely statistical, and therefore not suitable for this site. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400128/warningtensorflowlayer-my-model-is-casting-an-input-tensor-from-dtype-float64) about a short discussion on Tensorflow and default data types.

Comment: As @NicolasGervais correctly points out, and for the next time, please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info) (applicable also to `deep-learning` questions).

Comment: Thank you both (desernaut and @NicolasGervais for the observations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The normalization is recommended as it was empirically observed that
   the network converges faster and to better global optima when all
   the pixel values lie between (0 and 1) rather than 0 and 255.0. You
   can try to see how the network behaves when you train with the
   values between 0 and 1.0 and 0 and 255.0.
2. The mask value does not need to be converted, leave it as it is(presuming you are doing image segmentation), just ensure the labels are correct.
3. Yes, the same preprocessing that is applied during the training must be applied during the testing scenario/future predictions, otherwise your model will not work.

Comment: If you're aware that this question needs to be closed, why are you answering it? This prevents the mighty [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) from doing its job.

Comment: Because I think that the question asker needs to be first helped and then "admonished"/pointed in the right direction, considering that not everybody is very aware of /experienced with the entire flow. At the same time, the user got the answer, I explained to him in the comments why it is not suitable, but answered his dillema. Rather than letting the user with the question unanswered and "punishing him/her" directly, I consider my approach to be an alternative. Although I perfectly understand your point, and myself I choose the "close" approach most of the time.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I was not even aware of the Roomba process!

Comment: @TimbusCalin thank you for give me an answer instead of just closing directly closing the question. It helped me in both ways: Solving my doubts and teaching me how to proceed in the future.

Comment: Thank you NicolasGervais and @desernaut for the observations and additions.